# Incorrect Result from Selection Sort Algorithm

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

// Selection Sort function.
// Parameter 'a' is the size of the array.
void ss(int AR[] , int a) {
    int small;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <a ; i++) {
        small = AR[i]; 
        for (int j = i+1 ; j <a ; j++) {
            if (AR[j]< small) {
                int k = AR[j];
                AR[j] = AR[i]; 
                AR[i] = k;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Enter the size of Your Aray";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    int AR[a];
    cout << endl; 
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cin >> AR[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    ss(AR, a);
    cout << "The Sorted Array is"; 
    for (int i=0; i < a; i++) {
        cout << AR[i] << " ";  
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

When I enter the following:

- 15
- 6
- 13
- 22
- 23
- 52
- 2

The result returned is:

- 2
- 13
- 6
- 15
- 22
- 23
- 52

What is the bug preventing the list from being sorted numerically as expected?

Comment: Please format your code so that it is reasonably readable, and also notice that your caps lock key appears to be on.

Comment: Use your debugger, that's what it's for!

Answer (score 1):

The function can look like

```
void ss ( int a[], size_t n )
{
   for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
   { 
      size _t small = i;

      for ( size_t  j = i + 1; j < n ; j++ )
      {
         if  ( a[j] < a[small] ) small = j;
      }

      if ( i != small )
      {
         int tmp = a[small];
         a[small] = a[i];
         a[i] = tmp;
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be the SelectionSort I know. in the algorithm I know during every loop I look for the smallest element in the right subarray and than exchange it with the "pivot" element of the loop. Here's the algorithm

```
void selectionSort(int* a, int dim)
{
   int posMin , aux;
   for(int i = 0; i < dim - 1; ++i)
   {
      posMin = i;
      for(int j = i + 1; j < dim; ++j)
      {
         if(a[j] < a[posMin])
            posMin = j;
      }
      aux = a[i];
      a[i] = a[posMin];
      a[posMin] = aux;
   }
}
```

and it seems that you change every smaller element you find, but also change the position of the "pivot". I hope the answer is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok in the original function, only that the `small` variable need to be refreshed when two vector elements will be switched.
Also in if statement set the `small` variable to the new value of `AR[i]`.